# Fail to install Psycopg2 in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, psycopg2

I'm using Jenkins Pipeline on CentOS 6 and I want to install python 3.5 dependencies with this Jenkins Pipeline job.

My Declarative Pipeline is,

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('InstallPythonDeps') {
            steps {
                sh "./InstallPythonDeps.sh"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `InstallPythonDeps.sh` is,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin
# I uses pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv
sudo /var/lib/jenkins/.pyenv/versions/my-virtualenv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
echo $PATH
which pg_config
```

---

But I still saw the message `Error: pg_config executable not found.` when I installed `psycopg2` with `pip`, even though,

- The result of `echo $PATH` is `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin`
- The result of `which pg_config` is `/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config`

---

`yum` libs are,

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep postgresql
postgresql93.x86_64                9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6            @pgdg93
postgresql93-devel.x86_64          9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6            @pgdg93
postgresql93-libs.x86_64           9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6            @pgdg93
postgresql93-server.x86_64         9.3.16-1PGDG.rhel6            @pgdg93

$ sudo yum list installed | grep python-devel
python-devel.x86_64                2.6.6-66.el6_8                @updates
```

---

I don't understand why `pg_config` not found while `pip install`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for myself,

I changed my `InstallPythonDeps` script to,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

pyenv activate psapi
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I don't know exactly why work this...